# How to define and run a function for a hover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have defined a function like so:

```
var hovername = function() {                        
    // do something
}, function() {
    // do something
});
```

But when I call it using `somevariable.hover(hovername);`, it displays an error: Missing variable name `}, function() {`.

I removed the second function and it works okay but the mouseout part of the hover event is gone.

How do I define a function then for a hover event which accommodates for the mouseout event? Or do I use mouseout and mouseover events instead of just hover?

Comment: Take a look at [the syntax for the `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

jQuery hover accepts 2 parameters as functions.

You can either do it such is

```
var hoverIn = function () {},
    hoverOut = function () {};

$('#el').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
```

or with annoymous functions

```
$('#el').hover(function () {}, function () {});
```

Your problem lies within the 2nd declaration of a missing variable name and you're only passing in one of the parameters.

var hovername = function() {
    // do something
}, function() { // missing a variable name here
    // do something
});

```
somevariable.hover(hovername, // missing 2nd function);
```